# Tkinter | Setting text for specific columns - py3.5

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a table with `tkinter`

I would like each column to have the text `a,b,c,d,e` in order like so:

### | a | b | c | d | e |

My current code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

width = 5
defaultRow = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for j in range(width):
    for l in defaultRow:
        setText = StringVar()
        b = Entry(root, textvariable=setText, state='readonly')
        setText.set(l)
        b.grid(row=1, column=j)

root.mainloop()
```

However, the output is just :

### | e | e | e  | e | e |

Isn't my code meant to loop through the list and set the text for the next item in `l` with the next column `j` ?

Comment: Consider using a collection type(dict, list, tuple, set) as opposed to overwriting variables each time for loop runs.

Comment: Thanks @Nae I will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested **two** loops here, but intended to iterate just over **one** list.
To achive your desire, you just need to adjust your code:

```
root = Tk()
defaultRow = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'E']
for j in range(len(defaultRow)):
    setText = StringVar()
    b = Entry(root, textvariable=setText, state='readonly')
    setText.set(defaultRow[j])
    b.grid(row=1, column=j)
root.mainloop()
```

with the nested loop, you were going to

```
column 1 -> set: "a"
column 1 -> set: "b"
column 1 -> set: "c"
column 1 -> set: "d"
column 1 -> set: "e"
column 2 -> set: "a"
column 2 -> set: "b"
...
```

resulting all column to have "e" at the end

Comment: Instead of `range()` I would use `enumerate()` to iterate over a number *and* the values in `default_row`.